# Wijmo grid displays improper Date

Tags: wijmo, wijgrid

I am trying to use wijmo controls for my application with integration of knockoutjs and hottowel spa template. It works fine. but it displays wrong dates that should not be occur like "2013-42-18 11:42 PM".
i am providing the datatype like " dataType: 'datetime', dataFormatString: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm tt'".

Thanx

Prince Chopra

Answer (score 1):

Please change the dataFormatString to "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt". 'mm' is used to denote minutes, whereas 'MM' is used to denote months.

Comment: Yes it works fine by using "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm tt". Thanks @AbdiasM